# Marshalling C array in C# - Simple HelloWorld

Tags: c#, c, arrays, pointers, marshalling

Building off of my [marshalling helloworld question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296722/marshalling-nested-struct-between-c-sharp-and-c-simple-helloworld), I'm running into issues marshalling an array allocated in C to C#. I've spent hours researching where I might be going wrong, but everything I've tried ends up with errors such as [AccessViolationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

The function that handles creating an array in C is below.

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl import_csv(char *path, struct human ***persons, int *numPersons)
{
    int res;
    FILE *csv;
    char line[1024];
    struct human **humans;

    csv = fopen(path, "r");
    if (csv == NULL) {
        return errno;
    }

    *numPersons = 0; // init to sane value
    /*
     * All I'm trying to do for now is get more than one working.
     * Starting with 2 seems reasonable. My test CSV file only has 2 lines.
     */
    humans = calloc(2, sizeof(struct human *));
    if (humans == NULL)
        return ENOMEM;

    while (fgets(line, 1024, csv)) {
        char *tmp = strdup(line);
        struct human *person;

        humans[*numPersons] = calloc(1, sizeof(*person));
        person = humans[*numPersons]; // easier to work with
        if (person == NULL) {
            return ENOMEM;
        }
        person->contact = calloc(1, sizeof(*(person->contact)));
        if (person->contact == NULL) {
            return ENOMEM;
        }

        res = parse_human(line, person);
        if (res != 0) {
            return res;
        }

        (*numPersons)++;
    }
    (*persons) = humans;

    fclose(csv);

    return 0;
}
```

The C# code:

```
IntPtr humansPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
int numHumans = 0;

HelloLibrary.import_csv(args[0], ref humansPtr, ref numHumans);

HelloLibrary.human[] humans = new HelloLibrary.human[numHumans];
IntPtr[] ptrs = new IntPtr[numHumans];
IntPtr aIndex = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(humansPtr, typeof(IntPtr));

// Populate the array of IntPtr
for (int i = 0; i < numHumans; i++)
{
    ptrs[i] = new IntPtr(aIndex.ToInt64() +
            (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) * i));
}

// Marshal the array of human structs
for (int i = 0; i < numHumans; i++)
{
    humans[i] = (HelloLibrary.human)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
        ptrs[i],
        typeof(HelloLibrary.human));
}

// Use the marshalled data
foreach (HelloLibrary.human human in humans)
{
    Console.WriteLine("first:'{0}'", human.first);
    Console.WriteLine("last:'{0}'", human.last);

    HelloLibrary.contact_info contact = (HelloLibrary.contact_info)Marshal.
        PtrToStructure(human.contact, typeof(HelloLibrary.contact_info));

    Console.WriteLine("cell:'{0}'", contact.cell);
    Console.WriteLine("home:'{0}'", contact.home);
}
```

The first `human struct` gets marshalled fine. I get the access violation exceptions after the first one. I feel like I'm missing something with marshalling structs with struct pointers inside them. I hope I have some simple mistake I'm overlooking. Do you see anything wrong with this code?

See this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/erichschroeter/df895f2855af0fc89dd5) for full source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  // Populate the array of IntPtr
```

This is where you went wrong.  You are getting back a pointer to an array of pointers.  You got the first one correct, actually reading the pointer value from the array.  But then your for() loop got it wrong, just adding 4 (or 8) to the first pointer value.  Instead of reading them from the array.  Fix:

```
    IntPtr[] ptrs = new IntPtr[numHumans];

    // Populate the array of IntPtr
    for (int i = 0; i < numHumans; i++)
    {
        ptrs[i] = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(humansPtr, typeof(IntPtr));
        humansPtr = new IntPtr(humansPtr.ToInt64() + IntPtr.Size);
    }
```

Or much more cleanly since marshaling arrays of simple types is already supported:

```
    IntPtr[] ptrs = new IntPtr[numHumans];
    Marshal.Copy(humansPtr, ptrs, 0, numHumans);
```

I found the bug by using the Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1.  Put *humansPtr* in the Address field, switched to 4-byte integer view and observed that the C code was doing it correctly.  Then quickly found out that ptrs[] did not contain the values I saw in the Memory window.

Not sure why you are writing code like this, other than as a mental exercise.  It is not the correct way to go about it, you are for example completely ignoring the need to release the memory again.  Which is *very* nontrivial.  Parsing CSV files in C# is quite simple and just as fast as doing it in C, it is I/O bound, not execute-bound.  You'll easily avoid these almost impossible to debug bugs and get [lots of help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks! I'm writing code like this because I need it to be run cross platform. The C code is a library that will be run on embedded and desktop Linux as well as Windows. I provide a CLI on Linux, but Windows needs a GUI and I prefer writing C# for GUIs on Windows.

I am fairly new to using C code in C#, so I don't know all the best practices. This was a trivialized example of my actual code, where I provide a function to free the memory allocated in C.